# adjusting Gridview to the whole screen

Tags: android

I ma facing issue with adjusting gridview to the whole screen. the following is my code:

activity_main.xml having gridview:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.esoftall.esoft.MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls1"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay">

     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls2"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="#508493"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent"
             >

     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/auto_complete"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>    

     <AutoCompleteTextView
      android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="10"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
      android:textColor="#000000" >
      <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>


   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <GridView 
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@+id/grd1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
     />

    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

name.xml code which is linking to the grid view from imageadapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/white_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="20dip"
            android:radius="10dip"
            >

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/images"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        />
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls3"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="#508493"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            >
   <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/white_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >  
    <TextView 

    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/img_text"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is the image display of gridview:[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In your `GridView` , try to set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697681/android-gridview-adjusting-to-screen-size

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the android:padding="5dp"

example code:

```
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:text="@+id/grd1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
     />
```